# SQL Query for Getting total amount in each row

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two Tables one is Ledgers in Ledgers there are fields Name and LedgerId.
and there is another table transactions which has fields transId,Date,ledgerId,Amount.

```
tables :-
Ledgers        transactions
--------      ------------
LedgerId        transId
Name            Date
                ledgerId
                Amount
```

when collecting amount from each ledger it will store to transaction table with ledger id, the report I need is to get the list of the transaction between two dates. the report will be.

```
 Date, Name, Amount, Total Amount so far
```

how to fetch total amount using the query, the total amount means how much amount in a ledger when he/she deposit that time. for example.

```
   Date        Name     Amount in Date        Total Amount so far
 21/08/2017     Jon        100                 100 (this is total of Jon's transaction)
 22/08/2017     Danny      20                  20 (this is total of Danny's transaction)
 23/08/2017     Jon        50                  150 (this is total of Jon's transaction)
 24/08/2017     Danny      10                  30  (this is total of Danny's transaction)
```

so I want total amount so far column will be the total amount of that ledger til that date.how can I do that by the query?

Comment: sql-server or ms-access ?

Comment: Is this MS Access or SQL Server? Or both?

Comment: Do you want to sum only those transactions between the specified dates? Or do you want to sum all records up to the end date? Consider building a report and use its Sorting and Grouping with aggregate calcs features. Textbox on report has a RunningSum property. Otherwise, review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#YTD

Comment: How does danny have a total of 50 and 60?

Comment: @June7  i want specified dates

Comment: @Shawn i am using ms access

Comment: @scsimon i have changed the danny's total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t.Date, l.Name, t.Amount,
       (SELECT SUM(Amount) 
        FROM transactions t2 
        WHERE t2.ledgerID = t.ledgerID
        AND t2.date <= t.date) as TotalAmountToDate
FROM ledger l
JOIN transactions t on l.ledgerID = t.ledgerID
```

This will work in SQL Server, not totally sure about Access.

Comment: well I've got the logic i will check on ms access.thank you.